# Good Entity Framework sample applications?

Tags: entity-framework

I am looking for some good asp.net sample applications which use Entity Framework. I saw a couple apps for NorthWind (one was MVC based). Looking for one with is more sophisticated than the simple apps at MSDN (HRSkillsCombined, CourseManager,AdWksSalesWinDataBind,  ResearchCollaborationAssistant). Possibly using Entity Inheritance, multi table change tracking.. etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a work in progress, but Microsoft's Danny Simmons has started [a series of posts on implementing a MUD using the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsimmons/archive/tags/D3/default.aspx). He's discussing not only how to use the Entity Framework itself (and he's one of the most qualified people to do that), but also how to use it in the context of the architecture of the application.

Here's a [free book on the Entity Framework with a complete sample project](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/12/18/my-christmas-present-to-the-entity-framework-community.aspx).