# ASP.NET / C# SqlDataSource commands and parameters based on table

Tags: c#, parameters, telerik, sqldatasource

Is there any way to generate CRUD commands and parameters for SqlDataSource based on table name? Idea is to make only one page for handling lookup tables, which can have different columns, so SqlDataSource attached to Teleriks RadGrid could fill all commands and parameters having table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this dynamically changing CRUD commands properties on DropDown `SelectedIndexChange` event. Anyway Entity Framework will be something that I will learn

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a complete answer, but hope this will at-least be a good start. Have a look at the [Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555062/good-entity-framework-sample-applications), and/or [T4 Templates](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/How-Do-I-With-T4-Editor-Text-Templates.htm) (there's also a VS add-on for it, for syntax highlighting). Otherwise you'd have to have to look at an answer making use of generics of sorts